Firebase auth with jest in react native
trying to mock my firebase function in react native  with the following
   it("should call signupWithEmailAndPassword when the sign-up button is pressed", async () => {
      const { getByTestId } = renderComponent();

      const emailInput = getByTestId("email-input");
      const passwordInput = getByTestId("password-input");
      const confirmPasswordInput = getByTestId("confirm-input");

      fireEvent.changeText(emailInput, "test@example.com");
      fireEvent.changeText(passwordInput, "password123");
      fireEvent.changeText(confirmPasswordInput, "password123");

      // Simulate sign-up button press

      const signUpButton = await waitFor(() => getByTestId("signup-button"));
      fireEvent.press(signUpButton);

      // Wait for any asynchronous operations to complete
      await waitFor(() => {
        const createUserWithEmailAndPassword =
          require("@react-native-firebase/auth").auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword;
        expect(createUserWithEmailAndPassword).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(createUserWithEmailAndPassword).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
          "test@example.com",
          "password123"
        );
      });
    });

but keep getting  Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0
trying to see if the createUserWithEmailAndPassword test works
ideally Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 1
